# Горячие клавиши для IDE Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Использую Netbeans 8.0.2 возникла необходимость выводить при нажатии клавиш например тег `<pre></pre>` или `var_dump()`. Как это можно настроить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

есть вариант используя `Code Template`

[image: Code template]

1. нужно написать пару букв, к примеру

`pr - для <pre></pre>`

`vr - для var_dump();`

2. Второй колонке указываете сам код
3. в коде пишете `vr` и нажимаете <kbd>Tab</kbd>

4*. вместо <kbd>Tab</kbd> можно еще <kbd>Пробел</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Пробел</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]